# Splicing in Terraform

Tags: terraform

So I am trying to understand the following expression:

`split("/", str)[0]`

I get that the split function divides a given string at every /, but what does the last part do ([0])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` function returns a list and thus `[0]` is a reference to index number of the list element.

Test out different functions with ease using `terraform console`, e.g.:

```
-> split(",", "foo,bar,baz")
tolist([
  "foo",
  "bar",
  "baz",
])
-> split(",", "foo,bar,baz")[0]
"foo"
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to define temporary variables in the console?

Comment: You can load locals on console startup since terraform 0.12 - check this issue for example: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18413#issuecomment-434875939

Answer (score 1):

`split()` returns a list of strings. The `[0]` index selects the first string in that list.

`split("/", "foo/bar")` would return the list `["foo", "bar"]`

`split("/", "foo/bar")[0]` would return the string `"foo"`